# Error in logging in with facebook app using php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

As a newbie in facebook apps , I copied the social-cafe facebook app and tried to publish it using all the details that was provided in the readme files . 
I read the basics of the facebook app from [here](http://developers.facebook.com)

For instance my app is not publishing story to stream.Actually I am not able to login through my app ,, :(

All tags are there, graph api is all set ,but still app is not working.

The problem is that when I click a drink to post it to my stream, I get an error that says:

There was a problem with your purchase. Please Login again.

In debug Tool got this Info:-

Response Code: 206

Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed

Inferred Property:  The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Small og:image: All the images referenced by og:image should be at least 200px in both dimensions. Please check all the images with tag og:image in the given url and ensure that it meets the recommended specification.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you gone through the open graph tutorials? Its a different concept and you have to get the OG action approved by facebook before using it, have you done that?

Comment: You may follow these steps to create login with facebook:
    http://www.w3lessons.com/2012/01/facebook-login-integration-with-website.html

Comment: @Sahil
I haven't published the app for now ,, I am currently developing the app ,, so for developers I think the OG section is already approved !

Comment: But have you defined the actions in the OG or not?

Comment: Moreover, you will need to create a publicly accessible web page that represents this object using Open Graph metatags. have you created that? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/opengraph-tutorial/#publish

Comment: Also Your action must be published at least once to your Timeline before submitting this action type .

Comment: @Sahil
yes ,, they are already defined ,,

Comment: @sandip 
that was not what I meant :(

Comment: @Sahil As I read the readme file for the app, no such publicly accessible webpages were mentioned ,, So I didn't do it ,, 
If you know how to handle this ,, Please tell me !

Comment: The file that is containing the meta tags, should be live at a server, so that the facebook can access it.

Comment: I have the codes for my action types ,, so what should I do know ,, 
where should I paste it ?